# Determine which apps run on startup

Tags: linux, centos, centos6, chkconfig

I have a CentOS 6 32bit VPS and I'd like to determine, How do I know which apps automatically run on startup?

**EDIT:** I have tried `chkconfig --list` but I don't understand what these lines meant:

```
[root@server2 ~]# chkconfig --list
dropbox         0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
httpd           0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:off   5:off   6:off
iptables        0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
modules_dep     0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
mysqld          0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:off   5:on    6:off
named           0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
netconsole      0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
netfs           0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:on    5:on    6:off
network         0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
nginx           0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
nmb             0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
nscd            0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
openvpn         0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
rdisc           0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
rpcbind         0:off   1:off   2:on    3:off   4:on    5:on    6:off
rsyslog         0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
saslauthd       0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:off   5:off   6:off
smb             0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
snmpd           0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
snmptrapd       0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
sshd            0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
udev-post       0:off   1:on    2:on    3:off   4:on    5:on    6:off
xinetd          0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the command runlevel to find what is the run level, which is the number before on or off. So if your run level is 2, you can grep 2:on from the above output and find all the services that are on. Usually run level is set in /etc/inittab, but can be changed.

Answer (score 2):

The columns 0-6 are your runlevels. Basically the columns indicate which services are started/stopped at what system stage or run level.

See also:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runlevel

https://serverfault.com/search?q=what+is+a+runlevel

Most systems/servers operate at runlevel 3, aka: 'init:3' in inittab terms.